Как приплюсовать к цене значения из кастомных полей woocommerce
Я реализую добавление ингредиентов к товару на сайте wordpress+woocommerce.
При добавлении ингредиентов должна изменяться сумма в соответствии с выбранным ингредиентом, но у меня прибавляется только первый и последний ингредиент. Это сводит меня с ума. Благодарю за любую помощь
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_ingredient_fields' );
function add_ingredient_fields() {
    global $product, $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => 'ingredients',
        'label'       => __( 'Ингредиенты', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Введите ингредиенты через запятую', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => __( 'Перечислите ингредиенты, доступные для этого товара.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ingredients', true ),
    ) );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => 'ingredient_prices',
        'label'       => __( 'Стоимость ингредиентов', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Введите стоимость ингредиентов через запятую', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description' => __( 'Введите стоимость каждого ингредиента в том же порядке, в котором они перечислены в поле "Ингредиенты".', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ingredient_prices', true ),
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_ingredient_fields' );
function save_ingredient_fields( $post_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ingredients', wp_kses_post( $_POST['ingredients'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ingredient_prices', wp_kses_post( $_POST['ingredient_prices'] ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 'custom_add_to_cart_handler', 10, 1 );
function custom_add_to_cart_handler( $product_id ) {
    $selected_ingredients = isset( $_POST['ingredients'] ) ? (array) $_POST['ingredients'] : array();
    $ingredient_prices = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode( ',', get_post_meta( $product_id, 'ingredient_prices', true ))));
    $total_ingredient_cost = 0;
    foreach ( $selected_ingredients as $ingredient ) {
        $index = array_search( $ingredient, $ingredient_prices );
        if ( $index !== false ) {
            $total_ingredient_cost += (float) $ingredient_prices[$index];
        }
    }
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        $original_price = (float) $product->get_price(); 
        $new_price = number_format( $original_price + $total_ingredient_cost, 2, '.', '' ); 
        $product->set_price( $new_price );
        $product->save();
        wc_delete_product_transients( $product_id ); 
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    } else {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Не удалось добавить товар в корзину.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'view_ingredients', 61 );
function view_ingredients() {
    global $product;
    $ingredients       = explode( ',', get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ingredients', true ) );
    $ingredient_prices = explode( ',', get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'ingredient_prices', true ) );
?>
    <h3>Выберите ингредиенты:</h3>
    <form class="cart-ing" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>">

       <?php 
       // Проверка наличия ингредиентов
       if ( !empty( $ingredients ) ) {
           foreach ( $ingredients as $key => $ingredient ) {
               ?>
               <div>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $ingredient ); ?>" id="<?php echo sanitize_title( $ingredient ); ?>">
                   <label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $ingredient ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $ingredient ); ?></label>
                   <?php
                   if ( isset( $ingredient_prices[ $key ] ) ) {
                       echo ' (';
                       echo wc_price( $ingredient_prices[ $key ] );
                       echo ')';
                   }
                   ?>
               </div>
               <?php
           }
       } else {
           // Сообщение о том, что ингредиентов нет
           echo '<p>' . __( 'Для этого товара нет доступных ингредиентов.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
       }
       ?>

       <button type="submit" class="button"><?php echo __( 'Добавить в корзину', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
       <span id="price-element"><?php echo wc_price( $product->get_price() ); ?></span>
   </form>
   <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var input = $('.cart-ing input[type="checkbox"]');
  input.change(function (event) {
    var productId = $('input[name="add-to-cart"]').val();
    var selectedIngredients = [];
    var selectedIngredientPrices = [];
    $('.cart-ing input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (index) {
      var ingredientId = $(this).val();
      var ingredientPrice = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      selectedIngredients.push(ingredientId);
      selectedIngredientPrices.push(ingredientPrice);
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'update_product_price',
        product_id: productId,
        ingredients: selectedIngredients,
        ingredient_prices: selectedIngredientPrices
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log('Ответ от сервера:', response);
        if (response.success) {
          console.log('Новая цена:', response.data.data.price);
          // Обновляем цену
          $('.price').html(response.data.data.price);
        } else {
          console.error('Ошибка:', response.data);
        }
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log('Ошибка при обновлении цены: ', error);
      }
    });
  });
});
   </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_ajax_update_product_price', 'update_product_price');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_update_product_price', 'update_product_price');

function update_product_price() {
  if (!isset($_POST['product_id']) || empty($_POST['product_id'])) {
    wp_send_json_error('Invalid product ID.', 400);
    wp_die();
  }
  $product_id = intval($_POST['product_id']); // Sanitize as integer
  $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
  if (!$product) {
    wp_send_json_error('Product not found.', 404);
    wp_die();
  }
  $ingredients = isset($_POST['ingredients']) ? array_map('sanitize_text_field', $_POST['ingredients']) : array();

  $ingredient_names = explode(',', get_post_meta($product_id, 'ingredients', true));
  $ingredient_prices = explode(',', get_post_meta($product_id, 'ingredient_prices', true));

  $new_price = calculate_product_price($product, $ingredients, $ingredient_names, $ingredient_prices);

  wp_send_json_success(array(
    'data' => array(
      'price' => wc_price($new_price) // Форматируем цену
    )
  ));
  wp_die();
}

function calculate_product_price($product, $selected_ingredients, $all_ingredients, $ingredient_prices) {
  $base_price = $product->get_price(); 
  $new_price = $base_price;

  foreach ($selected_ingredients as $ingredient) {
    if (($index = array_search($ingredient, $all_ingredients)) !== false && isset($ingredient_prices[$index])) {
      $new_price += floatval($ingredient_prices[$index]);
    }
  }

  return $new_price;
}


Почему не использовать готовые плагины чтобы не сходить с ума?

хочу разобраться, плагин не нашла подходящий

плагинов полно

Для начала я бы попробовал не сразу суммировать += (на последнем этапе) , а создал массив и посмотрел, а видит ли Ваш перебор все значения, что вы пытаетесь передать и сложить.  Если нет, искал бы где у Вас ошибка и почему selected_ingredients не содержит нужных ингредиентов. То есть пошёл бы из конце к началу.
